# Convert integer into X characters string in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers, integer

I have an integer that I need to convert into a 4 digits string. I know the integer number is between 1 and 9999. If the number is 4, I want the output string to be "0004". If the number is 134, I need the string output as "0134" and so on.

What would be the shortest most elegant way of achieving this in PHP? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$string = sprintf( "%04d", $number);
```

Using [this demo](http://viper-7.com/BuFkfh):

```
foreach( array( 4, 134) as $number) {
    $string = sprintf( "%04d", $number);
    echo $string . "\n";
}
```

You get as output:

```
0004
0134
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 $num = 1;
 $paddedNum = sprintf("%04d", $num);
 echo $paddedNum;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your answer and the chosen one arrived at the same time and I had to choose one of them. I picked the first one on my list. Thanks you very much anyway, I have upvoted you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
str_pad($input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will work for integer and string both

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-pad.php

```
$input = 9;
$str = str_pad($input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //results in 0009
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sprintf with the %d option:

```
$NewString = sprintf( "%04d", $OldNumber);
```

the 04 tells sprintf how many digits your number should be, and will fill with zeros if it doesn't reach that number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = rand(1,9999);
echo sprintf( "%04d", $num);
```

Try this.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.